# Can all axioms of mathematical theories be expressed with predicate logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

The book *Roads to Infinity: The Mathematics of Truth and Proof* stated that, "All the standard mathematical theories have axioms that can be expressed
in predicate logic."  Predicate logic generally refers to any formal system like first-order, second-order logic, many-sorted logic, or infinitary logic, but it sometimes refers to just first-order logic (Wikipedia). The book never specified which it was referring to. I understand that not all axioms can be expressed in first-order logic, but what about in second-order logic, many-sorted logic or infinitary logic?

Comment: The axioms of ZFC can be expressed in first order logic (with equality) where the language is extended by a single binary relation symbol $\in$.

Comment: Axioms are sentences *of some particular language*, so I'm not sure what kind of notion of expressability you have in mind.

Comment: About the "expressive power" , see [Second-order and Higher-order Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/) and Stewart Shapiro,  [Foundations without Foundationalism : A Case for Second-Order Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=xm5eWgjpYU0C&printsec=frontcover) (1991).

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I'm asking if there are sentences expressed in mathematics that have no equivalent expression in predicate logic (in the general sense of the word).

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k: My point was, what does "expressed in mathematics" mean; and if they were not expressed in a predicate logic to start with, what kind of "equivalence" with a sentence of predicate logic do you have in mind? I think the question is ill posed.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine If it cannot be expressed in mathematics, perhaps it can be expressed in informal language. As for equivalence, I don't know how to describe it rigorously, as I don't know how to describe non-predicate (and nothing that can be represented with predicate logic, e.g. propositional logic), rigorously.

Comment: I think that's part of the issue: we don't really "informally axiomatize" theories because we want to be able to study said theories rigorously. It is also the case that there are structures that have no first order axiomatization (well orders, topological spaces), but which are nonetheless capable of being implemented in a theory that is first order (namely set theory), so for the purposes of your question I'm not sure how to count these. (I promise I'm not being difficult on purpose; I actually upvoted the question ;p)

Comment: ZFC is a first order logic with the added binary relation $\in$. What you are asking is if the logic is functionally (expressively) complete.

Comment: @KyleW That's not really what I'm asking. I know that even the basic operators AND and NOT are functionally complete, so presumably ZFC is as well.